# Composer firing scene show multiple times on one gotoScene("...") command

Tags: ipad, lua, coronasdk

I have a (Corona SDK) project to load a series of scenes (composer) and it seems on 3 of my scenes that load newVideo objects, the scene:show is being fired several times and I can't understand why.

The calling code looks like this:

```
local btn2 = self:getObjectByTag("button2");
    local function btn2_click(e) 
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
        composer.gotoScene("video_paulprice");
    end
end
btn2:addEventListener("touch", btn2_click);
```

The composer scene show method looks like this:

```
function scene:show( e )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = e.phase

    local halfscreenwidth=display.contentWidth/2;
    local halfscreenheight=display.contentHeight/2

    local bg = self:getObjectByTag("backgroundBox");
    bg.x= display.contentWidth/2;
    bg.y= display.contentHeight/2;
    bg.xScale=0.5;
    bg.yScale=0.5;

    print("CM PHASE: " .. e.phase)

    if (phase == "did") then
    video = native.newVideo( display.contentCenterX+1, display.contentCenterY-40, 535, 390 );
    local function videoListener( event )
        print( "Event phase: " .. event.phase );
    end
    video:load( "videos/video_1.mp4", system.ResourceDirectory );
    video:addEventListener( "video", videoListener );
    video:play()

    end 

    local btn1 = self:getObjectByTag("button1");
    local function btn1_click(e) 
        display.remove(video)
        composer.gotoScene("scene3");
    end
    btn1:addEventListener("tap", btn1_click);


    local btn2 = self:getObjectByTag("button2");
    local function btn2_click(e) 
        video:removeSelf()
        composer.gotoScene("scene4");
    end
    btn2:addEventListener("tap", btn2_click);

end
```

My terminal, debugger output looks like this:

```
2014-12-08 10:37:29.756 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.757 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.852 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.852 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.852 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.852 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.852 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.853 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.853 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: will
2014-12-08 10:37:29.885 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.885 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.885 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.885 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.885 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.886 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
2014-12-08 10:37:29.886 Corona Simulator[4392:175603] CM PHASE: did
Other scenes in my project the show method is only being fired once. I'm using build: Version 2014.2494 (2014.11.5)
```

Any help would be hugely helpful!

Thanks

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

After re-building the scenes manually, rather than using the compower UI in the latest build, the scenes now no longer fire show() / hide() / create() / destroy() many times - strange!

Maybe some sorts of weird bug in the composer ui? Have a thread working on this over on the corona SDK forums, will close this for now.

In short, my resolution was to recreate manually and position objects manually, rather than using the computer UI software in the latest build.